# ArcGIS Geocoding set everything to the same location

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, geocoding

I'm trying to geocode a bunch of locations (~4500) in Washington, DC based off their addresses. However, when I run it through the geocoding tool, each point gets set to the same XY location. What's the deal? Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: what locator are you using? what are your inputs?

Comment: @Maksim I was using the World Geocode Service (ArcGIS Online) and my input file has two location fields: address (i.e. 100 Q St. NE) and city (Washington, DC)

Comment: the result you are getting, what is in the addr_type field?

Comment: @Maksim all locations are being assigned 'Locality' addr_type

Comment: Your locations are being matched to whichever centerpoint ESRI determines for Washington, DC. Locality—A place-name representing a populated place such as a city or neighborhood. This is typically the smallest administrative division within a country, for example, Mustafapaşa, Gebze.

Comment: @Maksim Ah ok, so can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Your locations are being matched to whichever center point ESRI determines for Washington, DC.

Locality — A place-name representing a populated place such as a city or neighborhood. This is typically the smallest administrative division within a country, for example, Mustafapaşa, Gebze

The World Geocoding Service will return the most accurate results it has for your locations, apparently, Locality is as accurate as it can locate your addresses.

Try adding more specific info, a ZIP code perhaps. Maybe your locations are too newly updated to where the World Geocoding service does not have the reference data built in just yet.

Comment: Any other options besides adding a zip code? The data came to me without zip codes and there's hundreds of thousands of locations. I guess I could come up with a process to webscrape for the address' zip codes, but would that even fix my problem? Would hate to spend all that time working on a non-solution. I don't think the latter is my issue, unless all the addresses in DC are too new. Thanks

Comment: If within the World Geocoding locator service options, you are mapping the address information fields from your table to the Address and City fields, those are the best results you are going to get. Adding a ZIP Code field will probably give you ZIP center points, better than locality, but not what you are looking for I assume.